# ffmpeg does not work but VLC does

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

I am trying to read a streaming (http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream) using `ffmpeg`

The streaming works perfectly when I try it in VLC.

But in ffmpeg I get an error:

```
http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream: Input/output error
```

Why `ffmpeg` can't read it?

Here is the output:

```
$ ffmpeg -t 10 -i http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream -loglevel 1000 -y /tmp/x.wav
ffmpeg version N-63893-gc69defd Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 16 2014 05:38:01 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.101 / 55. 66.101
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '10'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '1000'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '/tmp/x.wav' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 1000.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 10.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream.
[http @ 0x3020d40] request: GET /stream HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/55.43.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: 150.161.93.174:8080


[http @ 0x3020d40] header='HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'
[http @ 0x3020d40] http_code=400
[http @ 0x3020d40] HTTP error 400 Bad Request
http://150.161.93.174:8080/stream: Input/output error
```